# Can you achieve nutritional requirements by consuming only organ meat?

Tags: vegetable, ketosis

I eat for the utility, not pleasure, as my career requires me to be as mentally sharp as possible at all times. Currently, I eat a keto-like diet which includes fish and veggies. I don't eat nuts as I am allergic.

I'm not a huge fan of the sugar content of vegetables, especially in that they knock me out of ketosis. I currently fast daily for ~19 hours (5 hour eating windows), which means that I typically intake a significant amount of sugar during a short period of time; through broccolli, cauliflower, etc.

I'm curious as to whether or not it may be advisable to swap the veggies out for organ meat—as organ meat (chicken hearts, etc) has a strong nutritional profile. It would be nice to cut sugar out of my diet completely. However, I'm worried that there may be unintended consequences or other things I am overlooking.

Looking forward to your kind advice. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know where you are but the main deficiency in diet in the USA is fibre, and you're proposing to worsen that.

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE, nikk wong! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. Personalised medical advice is off-topic here. You may improve your question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask]. You need to make this more general! Thanks!

Comment: Some organs might be dangerous when consumed in excess, e.g. liver of certain animals contain toxic levels of Vitamin A.

Comment: @Roland Those are livers of *wild* animals, not the ones you typically get from a supermarket (beef, lamb, chicken).

Comment: The answer is categorically no.  [You cannot process the nitrogenous products from converting protein to glucose if you get more than about 1/3rd of your calories from protein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_toxicity).  To avoid this with a high meat diet you are relying on the fat in meat to supply your energy.  Offal has very little fat, so you would be very vulnerable to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no-one can give you a definitive answer here. As mentioned, there have been cases of diverticulitis in low or no-fibre diets, but it is not known if the lack of fibre was the cause.

There is a growing movement led by Dr. Shawn Baker of people following a 'carnivore' / all meat diet, [many claiming](https://academic.oup.com/cdn/article/5/12/nzab133/6415894?login=false) to have exceptional results. But then, of course, many vegans experience exceptional results on a polar-opposite regime.

To answer your question, it is wise and probably safe to include vegetables in your diet. If you really want to reduce sugar content, swap your current cruciferous vegetables for leafy greens instead. Some of the longest-living populations in the world (i.e. Okinawans) make up 60 - 70% of calories through root vegetables!

Answer (score 3):

Your diet would be exceptionally devoid of vitamin C which exposes you to the risk of scurvy which can occur in 1~3 months, and used to be universally fatal.

Death occurs from intracranial hemorrhage, and seizures.

https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/125350-overview

I've only seen that in long distance lorry drivers on a diet of meat pies.

In addition the proposed diet is devoid of fibre which predisposes you to diverticulitis, and possibly autoimmune disease due to a disordered gut biome, but that is more speculative.

Comment: Are there any actual case reports of scurvy from people consuming "a keto-like diet which includes fish and [organ meat]" and without veggies?

Comment: @SridharRatnakumar Dr. Chiu announced last year that he was leaving SE, so I doubt you'll get a reply from him. If you want to ask a question, you should do exactly that. Just note that questions about diet and nutrition are off topic here, so your question needs to be primarily about scurvy, not the pros and cons of a keto diet.